# using instanceof in java

Tags: java, instanceof

I'm trying to implement a variation of s-java compiler. For that purpose I created a few classes that represent different variables. At some point I want to check if an assignment line like this `int a = b` is a legal assignment. (b could be any Variable) So i create an `IntVariable a` instance and b is an instance of some `Variable` and i am checking `b instance of a` to determine if b can be in fact assigned into a. This is only an example of the `instanceof` usage, I have a few other cases (b could be String literal or a number) and i am using the `instanceof` to see if any of the options that i know exist and are legal to determine if the assignment is legal.

My question is: can this be done in a better way not using `instanceof` or I just have to live with the fact that although its not so pretty it still works and other ways are much more complicated?

Edit:

```
public boolean convertable(Type other) {

  if (other instanceof FloatType || other instanceof DoubleType) {
     return true;
  }

     return false;
 }
```

Comment: add your current code snippet .. that will be more easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working on a s-java compiler, I think if you get `class` object of `other`, you could do more things

`Class otherClass = other.getClass();`

Once you have otherClass, you can do:

`otherClass.getClasses()`

Returns an array containing Class objects representing all the public classes and interfaces that are members of the class represented by this Class object.

OR

`otherClass.getDeclaredClasses()`

Returns an array of Class objects reflecting all the classes and interfaces declared as members of the class represented by this Class object.

Here's the reference:

Tutorial for Java reflection: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html

Java reflection API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also create some sort of unique-meta-class called "Type" which represents a type.
For every specific type (e.g. IntType, FloatType) you can create a new class. Then your variable can have a getType()-method which returns the reference to the specific type. Now you can compare types with "==" directly. "Type" can then have a methode which returns a list od types in which the first type can be converted.

For example:

```
interface Type
{
    public Collection<Type> getConvertibleTypes();
}
```

And then an IntType:

```
class IntType implements Type
{
    public static final IntType INST = new IntType();

    private IntType()
    {
    }

    public Collection<Type> getConvertibleTypes()
    {
        Collection<Type> v = new Vector<Type>();
        v.add(FloatType.INST);
        return v;
    }
}
```